# How can I use Formset in Django Form Wizard (and change dynamically the parameter extra)

Tags: django, forms, dynamic, wizard, formset

As you can see in my question, I'm trying to use a Formset in a Django Form Wizard and I would like to change the parameter "extra" depending on the previous step.

The way I proceed displays de right amount of forms but it seems that only the first form is saved and validated. Here is my "relevant" code (Sorry if it's not very clear, I'm new to Django...):

## VIEWS.PY

```
from django.forms import BaseFormSet            
HoraireFormset = formset_factory(HoraireForm,formset=BaseFormSet, extra=2)            
formset = HoraireFormset

FORMS = [("infos_generales", InformationsGeneralesForm),
         ("frequence_duree", FrequenceDureeForm),
         ("horaire", formset),
         ("confirmation", ConfirmationForm)
         ]

TEMPLATES = {"infos_generales": "inscription/infos-generales.html",
             "frequence_duree": "inscription/frequence-duree.html",
             "horaire": "inscription/horaire.html",
             "confirmation": "inscription/confirmation.html"}

class InscriptionWizard(SessionWizardView):


def get_template_names(self):
    return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
    form = super(InscriptionWizard, self).get_form(step, data, files) 
    step = step or self.steps.current

    if step == 'horaire':
        current_form = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('frequence_duree')
        days = current_form['jours']
        form.extra = len(days) # number of forms == number of days checked
        jours_de_la_semaine = ['Lundi', 'Mardi','Mercredi','Jeudi','Vendredi']
    return form 

def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
    context = super(InscriptionWizard, self).get_context_data(form=form,      **kwargs)
    if self.steps.current == 'horaire':
        step_0_data = self.storage.get_step_data('infos_generales')            
        club = Club.objects.get(pk = step_0_data.get('infos_generales-club'))
        current_form = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('frequence_duree')
        days = current_form['jours']
        modules = [Module.objects.filter(club=club, jour=day)[0] for day in days]
        context.update({'jours': modules})
    return context
```

## FORMS.PY

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django import forms
from models import Club, Frequence, Duree, Module

from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Field

# informations générales sur l'inscrit
class InformationsGeneralesForm(forms.Form):
    nom = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    prenom = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    club = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= Club.objects.all())
    telephone_contact = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email_contact = forms.EmailField()
    annee = forms.ChoiceField(label="Année d'étude", choices=(('1','1ère'),('2','2e'),('3','3e'),('4','4e'),('5','5e'),('6','6e'),),error_messages={'required': "Entrez votre année d'étude SVP"})
    ecole = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

from functools import partial
DateInput = partial(forms.DateInput, {'class': 'datepicker'})
from datetime import datetime
jours = ((0,'Lundi'),(1,'Mardi'),(2,'Mercredi'),(3,'Jeudi'),(4,'Vendredi'),)  

class FrequenceDureeForm(forms.Form):
    frequence = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= Frequence.objects.all())
    duree =     forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= Duree.objects.all())
    jours =     forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices= jours, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    date_debut = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(), required=True)

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data=super(FrequenceDureeForm, self).clean()
    date_debut=cleaned_data.get("date_debut")
     # Vérifie que les 2 champs sont validés
    if date_debut :
        if date_debut<datetime.now().date() :
            raise forms.ValidationError("Impossible de commencer les cours avant aujourd'hui...")
    return cleaned_data


# Horaire choisi (heure début et fin)
class HoraireForm(forms.Form):
    heure_debut = forms.TimeField(required=True, widget=forms.TimeInput(format='%H:%M', attrs={'class': 'timepicker','placeholder': "Introduisez l'heure à laquelle vous souhaitez commencer"}), input_formats=('%H:%M',))


 heure_fin   = forms.TimeField(required=True, widget=forms.TimeInput(format='%H:%M', attrs={'class': 'timepicker','placeholder': "Introduisez l'heure à laquelle vous souhaitez terminer"}),  input_formats=('%H:%M',))

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data=super(HoraireForm, self).clean()
    heure_debut = cleaned_data.get("heure_debut")
    heure_fin   = cleaned_data.get("heure_fin")
    # Vérifie que les 2 champs sont validés
    if heure_debut and heure_fin:
        if heure_debut>=heure_fin :
            raise forms.ValidationError("L'heure de fin du cours doit être supérieure à celle du début")
    return cleaned_data


# Sélection des modules (horaires et jours)
class ConfirmationForm(forms.Form):
    title = 'confirm'
```

SOLUTION
I finally got de solution. My error was in the template because I used a crispy form to render the form. I did the following modifications : 
1°. put the self.helper.form_tag to False in my form definition
2°. change in the template {{ wizard.form.management_form}} to {{ wizard.form|crispy}}

And that's it...